# hiltViewmodel() + navigation + composable Screen caused crash

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have a problem with using navigation +compose + hiltViewModel(). if I set hiltViewModel() in the screen constructor it causes a crash

@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
navController: NavHostController,
scaffoldState: ScaffoldState
) {
NavHost(
navController = navController,
startDestination = Screen.Home.route,
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {

```
    composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
        HomeScreen(navController = navController)
    }



        MovieAppTheme {
            // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
                    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

                    StandardScaffold(
                        navController = navController,
                        state = scaffoldState,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    ) {
                        SetupNavGraph(navController = navController, scaffoldState = scaffoldState)
                    }

                }
```

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
navController: NavHostController,
viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)

I don't want to create a new instance of the viewmodel in activity or screen.
when I delete the hiltviewModel code everything works fine! I try it with different versions of compose and I can't solve this problem!

Comment: Don't include screenshots of code: include the code directly in your question. Please also include the entire stack trace of the crash you are getting.

Comment: What's the stack trace of the crash?